# What is the meaning of this !(x == 1)

Tags: java, boolean, boolean-expression

I saw this expression `!(x == 1)` in a question.

While I understand that `x == 1` means `x` is equal to `1`, and `x != 1` means `x` is not equal to `1`.

What about this `!(x == 1)`, does it mean `x` is not equal to `1`?

Comment: Yes, it means exactly that.

Comment: `!` negates what is inside. So Java first evaluates `x == 1` and yields a `boolean` result, such as `true` or `false`. Then this is negated and all in all it computes **not equals**. But in two steps, as explained. As opposed to `!=` which is only one operator.

Answer (score 6):

`!` is the boolean negation operator. So, x is compared to `1`, as you suggested, and then the result is negated. This is equivalent to writing `x != 1`, and good IDEs will even suggest this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. `x != 1` and `!(x == 1)` both are same.

For an example if `x` is `2` the first one returns `true`.
In the second one `(x == 1)` this part returns `false`. And because of that negation of that, `!(x == 1)`   ==> `!(false)` returns `true`